# How to extract the hostname portion of a URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hostname

Is there a really easy way to start from a full URL:

```
document.location.href = "http://aaa.bbb.ccc.com/asdf/asdf/sadf.aspx?blah"
```

And extract just the host part:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.com
```

There's gotta be a JavaScript function that does this reliably, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 972, accepted):

Suppose that you have a page with this address: `http://sub.domain.com/virtualPath/page.htm`.

Use the following in page code to achieve those results:

| Property | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `window.location.host` | `sub.domain.com:8080` or `sub.domain.com:80` |
| `window.location.hostname` | `sub.domain.com` |
| `window.location.protocol` | `http:` |
| `window.location.port` | `8080` or `80` |
| `window.location.pathname` | `/virtualPath` |
| `window.location.origin` | `http://sub.domain.com` (Might include `:port` too*****) |

**Update: about the .origin**

***** As the [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) states, browser compatibility for `window.location.origin` is not clear. I've checked it in chrome and it returned `http://sub.domain.com:port` if the port is anything but 80, and `http://sub.domain.com` if the port is 80.

**Special thanks to @torazaburo for mentioning that to me.**

Comment: I have a web site and 2 applications in IIS. Eg: **sub.domain.com/v1** and **sub.domain.com/v2** and pages like ***sub.domain.com/v1/Default.aspx***  or _sub.domain.com/v2/Products/Default.aspx_ , etc. How I can get value ***/v2***, the root for my application ***sub.domain.com/v2*** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet use a javascript IDE like WebStorm, you get to see possible options as you write code.

Comment: `window.location.origin` is undefined in IE9 (according to the link, it's IE11+). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1368295/897326) helped.

Comment: Obviously helpful for almost everyone except it does not answer the question which is how to extract host part out of URL. Funny the correct answer with getRootUrl function has only 17 vs 609 votes.

Comment: @Miro the question is answered isn't it, the 2nd bullet point answers the question : window.location.hostname : you'll get sub.domain.com

Comment: @Paul suppose we have URL as string. Not object window with location.

Comment: window is not defined

Comment: `window.location.pathname` will **NOT** give `/virtualPath`. It will give `/virtualPath/page.htm`

Answer (score 169):

You could concatenate the location protocol and the host:

```
var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
```

For a url, let say `'http://stackoverflow.com/questions'`, it will return `'http://stackoverflow.com'`

Comment: it seems like you should use "hostname" rather than "host" to achieve the above results. source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725890/window-location-host-vs-window-location-hostname-and-cross-browser-compatibility

Comment: You can use location.origin with the same result.

Comment: The original question did not ask for the protocol portion of the URL.

Comment: The difference between `hostname` and `host` is [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11379802/1175496); `host` might include the **`port`**, where `hostname` does *not* include the `port`.

I think Christian used `location.host` here so the `var root` value will *include* the `port` value (if any). As @Sérgio says, why `var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host` **is equivalent** to `location.origin`;

Answer (score 59):

The accepted answer didn't work for me since wanted to be able to work with any arbitary url's, not just the current page URL.

Take a look at the [`URL` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL):

```
var url = new URL("http://aaa.bbb.ccc.com/asdf/asdf/sadf.aspx?blah");
url.protocol;  // "http:"
url.hostname;  // "aaa.bbb.ccc.com"
url.pathname;  // "/asdf/asdf/sadf.aspx"
url.search;    // "?blah"
```

Comment: One of the two answers here that don't assume you are on the browser side of things...

Comment: It doesn't work in Microsoft Internet Explorer 11. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 36):

Use `document.location` object and its `host` or `hostname` properties.

```
alert(document.location.hostname); // alerts "stackoverflow.com"
```

Answer (score 27):

There are two ways. The first is a variant of another answer here, but this one accounts for non-default ports:

```
function getRootUrl() {
  var defaultPorts = {"http:":80,"https:":443};

  return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname
   + (((window.location.port)
    && (window.location.port != defaultPorts[window.location.protocol]))
    ? (":"+window.location.port) : "");
}
```

But I prefer this simpler method (which works with any URI string):

```
function getRootUrl(url) {
  return url.toString().replace(/^(.*\/\/[^\/?#]*).*$/,"$1");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I like the 2nd method better too! especially when on server side javascript, no way to get window.location :)

Comment: One of the two answers here that don't assume you are on the browser side of things... But check the more recent one from Martin Konecny using new URL.

Answer (score 12):

Let's suppose you have this url path:

```
http://localhost:4200/landing?query=1#2
```

So, you can serve yourself by the **location values**, as follow:

```
window.location.hash: "#2"
​
window.location.host: "localhost:4200"
​
window.location.hostname: "localhost"
​
window.location.href: "http://localhost:4200/landing?query=1#2"
​
window.location.origin: "http://localhost:4200"
​
window.location.pathname: "/landing"
​
window.location.port: "4200"
​
window.location.protocol: "http:"

window.location.search: "?query=1"
```

Now we can conclude you're looking for:

```
window.location.hostname
```

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
document.location.host
```

or

```
document.location.hostname
```

Answer (score 7):

use

> window.location.origin

and for: "http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.com/sadf.aspx?blah"

you will get: http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.com/

Comment: This is great, but be warned that apparently it doesn't work on IE11 +  WIN7 https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4526233/

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

```
alert(window.location.hostname);
```

this will return host name as `www.domain.com`

and:

```
window.location.host
```

will return domain name with port like `www.example.com:80`

For complete reference check [Mozilla developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) site.

Answer (score 3):

There is another hack I use and never saw in any StackOverflow response :
using "src" attribute of an image will yield the complete base path of your site.
For instance :

```
var dummy = new Image;
dummy.src = '$';                  // using '' will fail on some browsers
var root = dummy.src.slice(0,-1); // remove trailing '$'
```

On an URL like `http://domain.com/somesite/index.html`,
`root` will be set to `http://domain.com/somesite/`.
This also works for localhost or any valid base URL.

Note that this will cause a failed HTTP request on the `$` dummy image.
You can use an existing image instead to avoid this, with only slight code changes.

Another variant uses a dummy link, with no side effect on HTTP requests :

```
var dummy = document.createElement ('a');
dummy.href = '';
var root = dummy.href;
```

I did not test it on every browser, though.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit late, but I made a clean little function with a little ES6 syntax

```
function getHost(href){
  return Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), { href }).host;
}
```

It could also be writen in ES5 like

```
function getHost(href){
  return Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), { href: href }).host;
}
```

Of course IE doesn't support `Object.assign`, but in my line of work, that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to specify something. If someone want to get the whole url with path like I need, can use:

```
var fullUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: why going longer way. It can be get with var fullUrl = window.location.origin+ window.location.pathname

Comment: but sometimes you want to add something like subdomain between the protocol and hostname e.g. multilanguage etc.

Answer (score 1):

Regex provides much more flexibility.

```
    //document.location.href = "http://aaa.bbb.ccc.com/asdf/asdf/sadf.aspx?blah
    //1.
     var r = new RegExp(/http:\/\/[^/]+/);
     var match = r.exec(document.location.href) //gives http://aaa.bbb.ccc.com

    //2. 
     var r = new RegExp(/http:\/\/[^/]+\/[^/]+/);
     var match = r.exec(document.location.href) //gives http://aaa.bbb.ccc.com/asdf
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution works in all web browsers including Microsoft Internet Explorer and doesn't use any regular expression, it's inspired of Noah Cardoza and Martin Konecny solutions:

```
function getHostname(href) {
    if (typeof URL === 'object') {
        // workaround for MS IE 11 (Noah Cardoza's solution but without using Object.assign())
        var dummyNode = document.createElement('a');
        dummyNode.href = href;
        return dummyNode.hostname;
    } else {
        // Martin Konecny's solution
        return new URL(href).hostname;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split the URL string using `/`

```js
const exampleURL = "Https://exampleurl.com/page1/etc/etc"
const URLsplit = exampleURL.split("/")
console.log(URLsplit)
console.log(URLsplit[2])
```

Result.   exampleurl.com