# How to get the host URL using JavaScript from the current page

Tags: javascript

Given that I'm on the following page:

```
http://www.webmail.com/pages/home.aspx
```

How can I retrieve the host name (`"http://www.webmail.com"`) with JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get host name in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/get-host-name-in-javascript)

Comment: I simply did `console.log(window.location)`. You will see all available attributes and their values. Only the port part is something you have to worry about, see answers below (or print the info on web page with non-standard port)

Answer (score 461, accepted):

```
// will return the host name and port
var host = window.location.host;
```

or possibly

```
var host = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
```

or if you like concatenation

```
var protocol = location.protocol;
var slashes = protocol.concat("//");
var host = slashes.concat(window.location.host);

// or as you probably should do
var host = location.protocol.concat("//").concat(window.location.host);

// the above is the same as origin, e.g. "https://stackoverflow.com"
var host = window.location.origin;
```

If you have or expect **custom ports** use **`window.location.host`** instead of `window.location.hostname`

Comment: Maybe don't specify `http` though. Use the relative protocol. Might be more appropriate than hard-coding one.

Comment: Thanks for updating it Eric, but it's still not correct. You don't need to reference location.protocol at all.

Comment: Use window.location.host instead of hostname, or it will fail if the port is not 80.

Comment: To use the relative protocol, as @Fuser97381 suggested (this way it will work for either http or https:
`var host = '//' + window.location.hostname`

Comment: BTW what is the point of using the `concat` function here rather than just using `+`? I don't see how using `concat` would have any advantage at all...

Comment: @MattBrowne When working with something that shall produce a string I'd say you should always use `concat`. In example `var a = 1 + 2 + " should be 12";` vs the concat version of this `var a = "".concat(1).concat(2).concat(" should be 12");`. Using concat will save you a lot of trouble `+` is for calculation, not concatenation.

Comment: `hostname` will give only domain and `host` will provide port also. This is great mini tool to see link anatomy http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/3070589

Comment: window.location.origin works well too - it includes the protocol and the port.

Comment: Confusingly `window.location.protocol` already contains a colon `:`, instead of actually merely the protocol … Pretty sure the protocols are actually named without `:`, as in `HTTP` and `HTTPS`, but I guess this is JS doing JS things.

Answer (score 113):

To get the hostname: [`location.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

But your example is looking for the scheme as well, so `location.origin` appears to do what you want in Chrome, but gets not mention in the Mozdev docs. You can construct it with

```
location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname
```

If you want the port number as well (for when it isn't 80) then:

```
location.protocol + '//' + location.host
```

Comment: Firefox 4 doesn't seem to have it, though Chrome 12 does. Is it defined in a specification?

Comment: Hi..For getting the port, the example worked like a charm..Thanks for that

Comment: FF supports location.origin since 21.0: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Answer (score 91):

You can get the protocol, host, and port using this:

```js
window.location.origin
```

---

## Browser compatibility

### Desktop

| Chrome | Edge | Firefox (Gecko) | Internet Explorer | Opera | Safari (WebKit) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Yes) | (Yes) | (Yes) | (Yes) | (Yes) | (Yes) |
| 30.0.1599.101 (possibly earlier) | ? | 21.0 (21.0) | 11 | ? | 7 (possibly earlier, see webkit bug 46558) |

### Mobile

| Android | Edge | Firefox Mobile (Gecko) | IE Phone | Opera Mobile | Safari Mobile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Yes) | (Yes) | (Yes) | (Yes) | (Yes) | (Yes) |
| 30.0.1599.101 (possibly earlier) | ? | 21.0 (21.0) | ? | ? | 7 (possibly earlier, see webkit bug 46558) |

All browser compatibility is from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Comment: I should mention IE does not support this.

Comment: Please do mention that it's a new feature and not supported by old browsers.

Comment: @kabirbaidhya How about verbose compatibility!

Comment: Good. But what happens when the MDN guys update the browser compatibility table, which happens pretty often with newer browser releases. You might need to keep on updating this to sync with their table ;).

Comment: Not really, this is the earliest know versions to support it not the latest and all browsers they look at already support it. This would only change if they decide to include another browser of can figure out the version numbers on some of the supported browsers which is somewhat moot since most newer ones are from their initial release.

Answer (score 12):

```
let path = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':' + window.location.port;
```

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your needs, you can use one of the [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) properties.
In your question you are asking about the *host*, which may be retrieved using `window.location.hostname` (e.g. `www.example.com`). In your example you are showing something what is called *origin*, which may be retrieved using `window.location.origin` (e.g. `http://www.example.com`).

```
var path = window.location.origin + "/";

//result = "http://localhost:60470/"
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
window.location.hostname
```

Comment: or `host` if you also need port

Answer (score 7):

You can try something like that:

```
1. Get the full URL:

     window.location

2. Get the only protocol:

    window.location.protocol

3. Get the host (without port):

    window.location.hostname

4. Get the host + port:

    window.location.host

5. Get the host and protocol:

    window.location.origin

6. Get pathname or directory without protocol and host:

    var url = 'http://www.example.com/somepath/path2/path3/path4';
    
    var pathname = new URL(url).pathname;
    
    alert(pathname);
```

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind before use **window** and **location**

**1.use window and location in client side  render  (Note:don't use in **ssr**)**

```
window.location.host;
```

or

```
var host = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
```

**2.server side render**

if your using nuxt.js(vue) or next.js(react) refer docs

**For nuxt js Framework**

```
req.headers.host
```

code:

```
async asyncData ({ req, res }) {
        if (process.server) {
         return { host: req.headers.host }
        }
```

Code In router:

```
export function createRouter (ssrContext) {



console.log(ssrContext.req.headers.host)   
      return new Router({
        middleware: 'route',
        routes:checkRoute(ssrContext),
        mode: 'history'
      })
    }
```

**For next.js framework**

```
Home.getInitalProps = async(context) => {
   const { req, query, res, asPath, pathname } = context;
   if (req) {
      let host = req.headers.host // will give you localhost:3000
     }
  }
```

**For node.js users**

```
var os = require("os");
var hostname = os.hostname();
```

or

```
request.headers.host
```

**For laravel users**

```
public function yourControllerFun(Request $request) {

    $host = $request->getHttpHost();

  

    dd($host);

}
```

or

**directly use in web.php**

```
Request::getHost();
```

Note :

both csr and ssr app you manually check
example
ssr render

```
if(req.server){
host=req.host;
}
if(req.client){
host=window.location.host; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I like this one depending of purpose

```
window.location.href.split("/")[2] == "localhost:17000" //always domain + port
```

You can apply it on any url-string

```
var url = "http://localhost:17000/sub1/sub2/mypage.html?q=12";
url.split("/")[2] == "localhost:17000"
url.split("/")[url.split("/").length-1] == "mypage.html?q=12"
```

Removing protocol, domain & path from url-string (relative path)

```
var arr = url.split("/");
if (arr.length>3)
   "/" + arr.splice(3, arr.length).join("/") == "/sub1/sub2/mypage.html?q=12"
```