# Is there any solution for getting current domain name by Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on ReactJs and the server direct to a domain name with id on it. So I want to ask how can I get current domain name with ReactJS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the host url using javascript from the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042007/how-to-get-the-host-url-using-javascript-from-the-current-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't React specific.

Just look at [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location):

```js
alert(window.location.hostname)
```

(Yes, the above snippet will say `stacksnippets.net` due to security reasons.)

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error: `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. It is jsdom jsdom-global library right?

Comment: `window` is innately available in browsers, you don't need a library. Are you running this in JSDom?

Comment: I found the answer. I use `context.req.url` of `getInitialProps` ReactJS, so I dont have to use `window`.

Comment: There is no "context.req.url" in raw ReactJS, so you left essential detail out of your original question. Glad you found the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Use window.location inside **componentDidMount** React Lifecycle. If you want to use inside DOM use **state** to store value.

Comment: I found the answer. I use `context.req.url` of `getInitialProps` ReactJS, so I dont have to use `window`.

Answer (score 1):

Use window.location.hostname - note this will not work in JSDom, only in browsers.