# Qt+wasm client-server communication

Tags: c++, qt, http, uri, webassembly

In Qt webassembly documentation there is a mention, than one can use `QNetworkAccessManager` for HTTP communication with the server that hosts my website. The problem is, that I can't hard-code URL for the server as it should be able to be deployed on any server. Is there a simple way to receive it somehow?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What server would you like to obtain the URL for? Do you have any code demonstrating the problem you're having?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042007/how-to-get-the-host-url-using-javascript-from-the-current-page) what you're looking for?

Comment: @JarMan The server that hosts a website. The question you linked, but in C++/wasm or Qt. OFC, I could build a bridge to receive it using JS eventually, if there is no a better way. But my intuition tells me it should be.

Comment: My recommendation would be to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64483285/edit) your question and give names to programs and server and client machines, and provide some [mre]. **In its current form, *your question is unclear*, so please improve it**, don't comment it.

Comment: I have developed a server/client computer vision app before by Qt for wasm. The server(written by Qt5, native codes) process the frames, then send the frames and results to the client(Qt5, wasm), the client can connect to the server by different url(it need to be https). I use websocket to communicate with the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, that I can't hard-code URL for the server as it should be able to be deployed on any server. Is there a simple way to receive it somehow?

Yes. Your server program runs a [QApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html), and the single instance of that class could get that URL.

In other words, you'll document that your C++ program (the executable file obtained by compilation, e.g. with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) `foo` would accept some `--server-url` argument, and you would start `foo --server-url http://example.com/somestrangeurl/`

Please notice that [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly) is often running inside Web browsers (that is, inside Web or [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) *clients*). Most HTTP servers (e.g. [lighttpd](https://www.lighttpd.net/)) are running on Linux OS (and you might use [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or some other HTTP *server* library for them, if you have to code your HTTP server from scratch).

Comment: It's not server that has to know its own IP. I need it in the clent (web browser) site to be able to send the request for the server. Just like regular JS applications normally does. The only difference here is that I am using Qt/wasm, not JS/html.

Comment: Hi Mariusz I got the same problem and so far looking for a solution. Did you get an answer?