# Perform a DNS lookup to resolve a hostname to an IP address using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dns

Is it possible to resolve a hostname using Javascript?

Here would be hypothetical code:

```
var hostname = "www.yahoo.com";
var ipAddress = DnsLookup(hostname);
console.log(ipAddress);
```

I am looking for that magic `DnsLookup()` function. :-)

Comment: @PatrikAlienus: you didn't understand the question. As [x-nl said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113072/resolve-a-hostname-with-javascript/31500047#comment36968223_7113122), your comment is "bollocks".

Comment: @DanDascalescu I guess the question I cite above is wrong. Having a checkmark and 277 upvotes...

Comment: @PatrikAlienus: the OP wants to resolve an *arbitrary hostname* to an IP. The answer you link to only gets *the hostname of the current page* from `window.location` and doesn't attempt to resolve it.

Comment: I would say that this question is almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113072/perform-a-dns-lookup-to-resolve-a-hostname-to-an-ip-address-using-javascript although you haven't stated whether you were using client-side script or server-side code like with NodeJS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I perform a DNS lookup (hostname to IP address) using client-side Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-perform-a-dns-lookup-hostname-to-ip-address-using-client-side-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

While there is no standard DNS functionality in JavaScript, you can always call a 3rd party public API that does DNS resolution.

For example, [Encloud provides such an API](https://www.enclout.com/api/v1/dns), and you can make an XMLHttpRequest for it:

```js
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = function () {
  var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  alert(JSON.stringify(response.dns_entries));
}  
oReq.open("get", "https://www.enclout.com/api/v1/dns/show.json?auth_token=rN4oqCyJz9v2RRNnQqkx&url=stackoverflow.com", true);
oReq.send();
```

Of course, you should get your own Auth token. Free Enclout accounts are limited to 6 request per minute.

If you just want the IP, make a GET request for http://api.konvert.me/forward-dns/yourdomain.com.

Comment: This resolves the hostname on the server of Enclout, not on the machine where the javascript is running.
Resulting IP could thus be different.

Answer (score 4):

There's a relatively new (2018) proposed Internet standard called [DNS over HTTPS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8484) (also called DoH) that's been taking off. It allows you to send wireformat DNS queries over HTTPS to "DoH servers". The nice thing is, with DoH you get the whole DNS protocol on top of HTTPS. That means you can obtain a lot useful information.

That being said, there's an open source JavaScript library called [dohjs](https://github.com/byu-imaal/dohjs) that makes it pretty easy to do a DNS lookup in the browser. Here's a quick example code snippet:

```js
const resolver = new doh.DohResolver('https://1.1.1.1/dns-query')
resolver.query('www.yahoo.com')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Full disclosure: I'm a contributor to dohjs.

There are a lot of resources on [cURL's DNS over HTTPS wiki page](https://github.com/curl/curl/wiki/DNS-over-HTTPS) including a list of public DoH servers and a list of DoH tools (mainly server and client software).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to callback to server-side and resolve the value from there. There is no standard DNS lookup functionality available in Javascript.

Answer (score -3):

No - javascript is blocked from making cross domain requests. There are potentially some hacks out there that might be able to help you ([this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) one looked kinda promising), but by default you can't do that.

You might be able to request something and make sure you get back a HTTP 200.

Comment: How is the referenced library going to help Amir get the IP address of the host?? Cross-domain requests have nothing to do with this - you can't resolve hosts on the front-end!

Comment: This answer is invalid. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/get-host-name-in-javascript/17336519#17336519

Comment: @PatrikAlienus Bollocks

Comment: No longer true in 2015 now that CORS is quite widely supported.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus The link you posted is irrelevant to this question and discusses a completely different issue.