# If domain specified not equal to then current URL apply this jQuery as well as pages with same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, url, jquery-events

The code below only shows `<span>` on http://example.com/ but wont show `<span>` on http://example.com/files/target.html so how can I get it to work on all pages with the specified domain? Please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myurl = "http://example.com/";
var currenturl = window.location
if(myurl != currenturl) {
$("<span style=font-size:200px;>big</span>").replaceAll("body"); // check replaceWith() examples
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote doesn't work because *window.location* returns a [Location](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#location) object, which is a host object. The variable *myurl* is a string. When comparing a string and an object using the equals operator, the string is compared with the result of calling the object's *toString* method.

Host objects don't necessarily have a *toString* method, so attempting to call it could throw an error. Even if the *location* object of the browser has a *toString* method, it could return a string that is the value of any one of those properties, or something else.

As it happens, in most browsers *window.location.toString()* will return the current URL (which is specified in [Moziall's Gecko DOM Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location)). However, *myurl* contains the string *http://myurl.com/* and the URL usually contains more information, such as the current page being displayed.

To match *myurl*, you need the protocol (http:) separator (//), hostname (myurl.com) and a trailing "/" character, so:

```
var loc = window.location;
myurl = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.hostname + '/';
```

Or you could format *myurl* to match one of the properties of the *location* object to make the comparison simpler.

PS. HTML5 is the first attempt at standardising the window object across browsers, so expect it to be a little different in different browsers—program defensively and test widely.

Comment: sorry to be a pain but I cant seem too get it to work could you please show me with the url in the correct place please.

Comment: I have it working now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/get-root-url-in-JavaScript fount the code from here very similar . thank you very much RobG I actually really appreciate it. thank you. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myurl = "www.myurl.com";
    var currenturl = window.location.hostname;
    if(myurl != currenturl) {
        $("<span style=font-size:200px;>big</span>").replaceAll("body"); // check replaceWith() examples
    }
</script>
```

Per MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location

Comment: I suppose that's a good thing, since `window.location.hostname` should always equal `www.myurl.com`, and if not, something is wrong. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Prevent someone from stealing my javascript because within it will be this an then they're blog will not function propperly. seems harsh but :/ :).

Comment: You can't prevent someone from stealing your javascript. It's on the client. Stop trying :)