# Getting the website root in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, path

say I'm developing a website.com. I need to get the root (website.com) dynamically (for dev and production). Is there a way to do it in JS?

I am using asp.net mvc 3 on the server.

Comment: You can use an ajax call to get it from the server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes: [window.location.hostname](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Javascript-Location-Hostname-with-Example.aspx)

Comment: While this works for this specific question (root guaranteed to be equal to host name), it doesn't address how to directly get the root URL in other cases.

Answer (score 3):

See: [How to extract the hostname portion of a URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/get-root-url-in-javascript)

Quote from the link:

> You could concatenate the location protocol and the host:
>   var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
>   For a url, let say 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions', it will return 'http://stackoverflow.com'

Comment: Did you change your question? I thought you asked a JS Question but maybe you want a asp.net answer?
For the host: `Request.Url.Host`

Answer (score 2):

I created a function to get real root:

```
function root() {
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' ),
            script = scripts[scripts.length - 1],
            path = script.getAttribute( 'src' ).split( '/' ),
            pathname = location.pathname.split( '/' ),
            notSame = false,
            same = 0;

        for ( var i in path ) {
            if ( !notSame ) {
                if ( path[i] == pathname[i] ) {
                    same++;
                } else {
                    notSame = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return location.origin + pathname.slice( 0, same ).join( '/' );
    }
```

call this function once when the js-file is loaded.
to make it work, you MUST include it as js-file.

## Usage:

```
var basepath = root();
```

here are some examples:

```
location.host: 'http://test.com'
location.path: '/myapp/controller/action/id'
```

this will result in:

```
http://test.com/myapp
```