# Javascript Get Website URL

Tags: javascript

How do I get Javascript to tell me the website url.

For example if I have a page `www.example.com/page.html`

I want Javascript to tell me the site url is `www.example.com` and not `www.example.com/page.html` (which document.location tells me)

Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: [`Location` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) have various properties that represent each segment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current URL with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get host name in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/get-host-name-in-javascript)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

> **There are several ways you can do this, but one way might be best for certain situations (e.g. within an iFrame).**

**Protocol + Domain + Page**

```
document.URL
> "http://example.com/page1.html"

document.location.href
> "http://example.com/page1.html"
```

---

**Protocol + Domain**

```
document.location.origin
> "http://example.com"
```

---

**Domain**

```
document.location.host
> "example.com"
```

---

**Page**

```
document.location.pathname
> "/page1.html"
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to get this.
Open Chrome browser and press F12, you'll get console.

Type following commands there for the same question URL. You will get your answer

```
window.location.hostname // Output : stackoverflow.com

window.location.origin // Output : http://stackoverflow.com

document.location.host // Output : stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
document.location.origin+document.location.pathname;
```

where `document.location.origin` will redirect you to `"http://www"`
and `document.location.pathname` will redirect you to "/stackoverflow/"(Name of your project).
In this way you can give reference to page or post you want in your js file.Suppose if i want reference to my home page i would have use

```
var address=document.location.origin+document.location.pathname;
 window.location.replace(address+"/home");
```

So using above example i can easily redirect to my homepage

Comment: Can you provide some details in your answer?

Comment: Hey Prikryl I have edited my answer .Did you get it now?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
window.location.hostname
```

You can test it by just typing it in the chrome dev tools console

Reference

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.location.host
```

Answer (score 0):

Use alert(window.location.origin) for getting the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.location.origin
```

That will give you the protocol and host.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `location.href` = `'/'` + `'path_name/sub_path_name'`

`'/'` = takes you to the home page then

`'path_name/sub_path_name'` = to pass the new path to the domain page