# How to set the first part of a url to a JavaScript variable in a HTML a link

Tags: javascript, variables, href

I've got a variable that gets the server url of the user:

```
var server = parent.Xrm.Page.content.getClientUrl;
```

I want to use that variable to be the first part of a html link and add the page name to the end of it to generate links for different pages. For example for the home page I need the a href to be a combination of var server and /homepage. I tried the following:

```
<a href="" onclick="this.href = 'server'+'/homepage" target="_blank">
```

But this didn't work. Any solution would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19550497/4903314

Comment: @UmairKhan I don't need to get the website url.. I already have that. I need to set it as a variable alongside and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an `onclick` method which will be implemented in javascript. There you will get the variable.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="" onclick="getUrl()" >
```

**JS:**

```
getUrl(){
window.open(server +'/homepage,  '_blank');
}
```

or you can send the extra string from html as parameter

```
<a href="" onclick="getUrl('/homepage')">
```

-

```
getUrl(url){
window.open(server + url,  '_blank')

}
```

Comment: The OPs `<a>` element has the `target` attribute set to `_blank` which will open the link in a new window/tab, `window.location = ..` will open the link in the current window/tab.