# How do I get the property that comes after the Domain name using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, localhost, hostname

[referenced from a previous SO question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/get-host-name-in-javascript)

If I have http://sub.domain.com/subpage/foo/page.htm .

I use this to get the host name:

```
window.location.hostname : you'll get sub.domain.com
```

Which is all good, but what if I also want to get `foo` as well.

What would I use then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.location.pathname` seems to be what you want.  For reference, you can enter `window.location` (or any other object) into your JavaScript console to get its properties.  For this page:

```
{
   "ancestorOrigins":{
      "length":0
   },
   "origin":"http://stackoverflow.com",
   "hash":"#21613466",
   "search":"",
   "pathname":"/questions/21613356/how-do-i-get-the-property-that-comes-after-the-domain-name-using-javascript/21613466",
   "port":"",
   "hostname":"stackoverflow.com",
   "host":"stackoverflow.com",
   "protocol":"http:",
   "href":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613356/how-do-i-get-the-property-that-comes-after-the-domain-name-using-javascript/21613466#21613466"
}
```

Comment: Is there any cleaner/lazy way to just get "questions" from 
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613356/how-do-i-get-the-property-that" without getting the whole path name?

Comment: @Nik `window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]`