# jQuery: determine the [server's] Document Root

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, document-root

in PHP you can get the document root by: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. Ej:

**PHP**

```
<?php
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path = '/example/directory/';
$file = 'some-file.html';

include( $root . $path . $file );

...etc
?>
```

How can I get the value of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in jQuery/JavaScript?

**jQuery**

```
//Example:
var root = ????;
var path = 'example/directory/';
var file = 'some-file.txt';

$("#example").load( root + path + file );
```

Notes: Whenever I work on directories, on an HTML page, the "BASE" directory becomes the directory of the current file. Ej, `www.ejample.com/documents/examples/this-ex.html`. If I just call `$("#example").load( path + file )` the request would be `documents/examples/ + example/directory`. Like I said, it's not a question about server-side stuff. Is about getting a correct (and automatic) directory position

Comment: js is client side, so you cant

Comment: look into this question- may be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/get-host-name-in-javascript

Comment: @dagon if you carefully read my question, you'll see that this is not a server-sided issue/question.

Comment: And if you had a basic understanding of what you are talking about, then you would be aware that a DOCUMENT_ROOT is a purely server-side construct, which has no client-side meaning _whatsoever_ …

Comment: The document root on the client site is very easy to get: `var root = '/';`

Comment: Whenever I work on directories, on an HTML page, the "BASE" directory becomes the directory I'm currently at, Ej, `www.ejample.com/documents/examples/this-ex.html`. If I just call `$("#example").load( path + file )` the request would be `documents/examples/ + example/directory`. Like I said, it's not a question about server-side stuff.

Comment: _“Whenever I work on directories, on an HTML page, the "BASE" directory becomes the directory I'm currently at”_ – that’s how relative paths are resolved, yes. And simply putting a leading slash in front of your `path` would probably solve your problem without any further effort …

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for `document.location.hostname`?

```
var root = document.location.hostname;

$("#example").load( root + path + file );
```

Comment: It's both, your answer and also `var root = '/';` as CRroe commented