# Check if homepage using window.location

Tags: javascript, url

Is it possible to check if I'm on the homepahge/index of a site using `window.location`?

I'm currently checking url using

```
window.location.href.indexOf("/category/something")
```

but how can I check for homepage? It doesn't contain any segments.

Note: I don't know what the homepage URL will be so I can't use for example a url name like `window.location.href.indexOf("myhomepage.html")`

**Update:** The only clue that I have is that the homepage has no URL segments.

Comment: By "homepage" do you mean the domain root?

Comment: If you don't know anything about the URL of your homepage then there is no way to test if you are on it by examining the URL.

Comment: The URL doesn't necessarily represents the actual page/file/action the server is serving/invoking. Typically, you'll need to rely on the application code to provide this information (and possibly expose it to the client-side as well).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get host name in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/get-host-name-in-javascript)

Comment: does the page (header/footer maybe) contain a link to the homepage? If so, grab that <a> and compare href to window.location.href

Comment: @isherwood no I'm no trying to get the host name. How would that tell me if i'm on the homepage?

Comment: @firien that seems to be the best way to check. If you post an answer with example i'll vote your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many site's homepage, including stackoverflow contain a link to that same homepage.

```
// browser url = http://example.com
<a href="http://example.com">my site</a>
```

If you have access to the source, you can identify this link server-side

```
<a id="homepage" href="http://example.com"/>my site</a>
```

So, to check if you are on the homepage:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  var link = document.querySelector('#homepage');
  if (link.href == window.location.href) {
    //i'm on the homepage
  }
})
```

---

So i just saw your update to the question. if you know there are no url segments, wouldn't `window.location.pathname` always be "/"

Answer (score 7):

The term `homepage` itself is a fairly vague construct and not something that is technically identifiable. You could have several different landing pages depending on your screen size, device, credentials, browser, date/time, geolocation, etc. etc.

The only way you can ensure you are on one of these landing pages is to be in control during the initial `GET` request to the domain (e.g. `http://www.example.com`).

So, if you're already on the page, there's no real way to **know** how you got there and if this is the default page provided from that domain, though there are hacks you could try to get a general *(albeit very error-prone)* idea.

For example, you could compile a list of common homepage paths:

```
var homepages = [ '/', 'index.html', 'index.htm', 'index.php', 'main.html', 'main.htm', 'homepage.html', 'index2.htm' ];
```

Then compare to the provided `window.location.pathname`:

```
if (homepages.indexOf(window.location.pathname) >= 0) {
    // we might be on a "homepage"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think one very obvious clue is no segments in the URL.

Comment: Yeah, that's the ideal situation, but there are plenty of sites that don't follow this convention. It's all about your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply did `window.location` and checked the args in there, if there are no pages/paths appended, url matches origin, etc., would that not be good enough to detect -- Idk, I've never had a need to do this?  This might also work for .NET and 'other' types of HTML naming conventions (i.e. index.html vs index.htm).  Additionally, if someone changes the doc root, or a home page pointer, you'd more or less know (aka not care) because window.location you can check the following:

```
window.location
Location {replace: function, assign: function, ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList, origin: "http://stackoverflow.com", hash: ""…}ancestorOrigins: DOMStringListassign: function () { [native code] }hash: ""host: "stackoverflow.com"hostname: "stackoverflow.com"href: "http://stackoverflow.com/"origin: "http://stackoverflow.com"pathname: "/"port: ""protocol: "http:"reload: function reload() { [native code] }replace: function () { [native code] }search: ""toString: function toString() { [native code] }valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }__proto__: Location
```

which has `path = '/'`.  That's pretty indicative of homepage'ish'ness.

Answer (score 1):

A JavaScript knows only it's current context. It has no idea where in a site's hierarchy it is, so no, you can't check if you're on the homepage without already knowing the homepage's URL