# Find server name from CSS href with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

How can I get the following server path assigned to a variable with jQuery or JavaScript ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://myServer:44301/Some/Path/">
```

From

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/assets/styles.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Site.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://myServer:44301/Some/Path/">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://anotherServer/Another/Path/">
```

The string `Some/Path` is what needs to be matched on.

To be clear, the variable should contain the string `https://myServer:44301/`

Comment: This link might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/how-to-get-host-name-in-javascript

Comment: you want to remove the particular link ahh??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function getHostWithPath(path) {
    var linkNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
    for (var i = 0 ; i <linkNodeList.length ; i++) {
        var l = document.createElement("a");
        l.href = linkNodeList[i].href;
        /*
        // Usefull properties available in l:
        console.log(l.hostname);
        console.log(l.port);
        console.log(l.pathname);
        console.log(l.hash);
        console.log(l.protocol);
        console.log(l.search); // Query String
        */
        if (l.pathname == path) {
            var re = new RegExp(path + '.*');
            return l.href.replace(re, '');
        }
    }
}

var myHostname = getHostWithPath('/Some/Path');
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to add the port number or connection protocol.

Comment: OK, sorry, I thought it was obvious, but there are more useful properties. Added in my answer, you can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/laruiss/h5ovo9dk/

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a much more powerful solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by JQuery by running the following code on your page:

```
var server = $("link[href*='/Some/Path']").attr("href").replace("Some/Path/", "");
```

What it does is it select the element whose *href* contains */Some/Path* and gets the whole *href* attribute's text/value. Then it removes the *Some/Path/* part leaving you with only `https://myServer:44301/`, which is then set in the variable `server` .

**Snippet:**

```js
var server = $("link[href*='/Some/Path']").attr("href").replace("Some/Path/", "");
alert(server);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/assets/styles.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Site.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://myServer:44301/Some/Path/">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://anotherServer/Another/Path/">
```

Comment: OK, what about... if it has a Query String? ;-) Like https://myServer:44301/Some/Path/?v1.0.2

Comment: Then my code would be `var server = $("link[href*='/Some/Path']").attr("href").split("Some/Path/")[0];` ... ;)

Comment: Your code would catch this : https://anotherServer/Another/Path/Some/Path/... My point being: your code does not seem to be very portable, reliable, reusable.

Comment: I agree that it lacks portability, but using `split` does expands its scope, by returning you anything thats before the specified text

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function() {
  $("link").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).prop("href");
    
    alert(href);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>title here</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/assets/styles.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Site.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://myServer:44301/Some/Path/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://anotherServer/Another/Path/">    
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- page content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The code below take each link and display them using `alert()`. Depending on your condition, I let you wrap the `alert()`with a condition bloc `if()` to take the right href (maybe your links are always set up like this, so you'll want to take the 3rd, etc...).