# How to resolve path issues in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the view I am getting the JSON data from the controller. Path is working in my local but not working in the other servers.

$.get('../TestController/GetTestResultById?Id=' + s.GetValue(), function (data) {
       some data
}

It is in this format I am getting the data in local but in different server the path should be appname/controllername/.... but getting as controllername/....
How to resolve this issue.

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/how-to-extract-the-hostname-portion-of-a-url-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

```
var myUrl = '@Url.Action("GetTestResultById","Test")';
//It will create your url where you want to call ajax.


//then append Id with url and your value.
$.get(myUrl + "?Id=" + s.GetValue(), function (data) { 
    // Use `data` here
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely adequate. Please explain your solution and why it solves the problem.