# How to get the last portion from the url using javascript ?

Tags: javascript

Currently I am on this page:

> www.mysite.com/page1/

Now I want to get the last portion from that URL which is `page1`

I am using the following but it's showing me full URL. I need only `page1`

```
var curPage = window.location;
```

How can I get this?

Comment: can you define *last portion*?

Comment: it's page1 from the full url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var curPage = window.location.pathname;
```

See this URL for more info

[How to extract the hostname portion of a URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/how-to-extract-the-hostname-portion-of-a-url-in-javascript)

Comment: Well, it's working but I am getting backslash and forward slash with page name. How can I delete it?

Comment: You could remove the chars you dont want using JS Splice or Replace method

Comment: If this solution has worked for you can you mark the answer as accepted, thanks

Comment: using replace method forward slash is removed from the start of the string not end

Comment: Got it. It's working. Thanks for help.

Comment: No problem, could you click the little green tick next to my answer to set it as the accepted answer? Thanks