# How to get the hostname in vuex action?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

I created app by nuxt.

I want to get hostname in vuex action ?

```
export const actions = {
  testAction({ commit }) {
    if (hostname === 'localhost') {
     commit ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to access it in the `nuxtServerInit` action?

Comment: You can set publicRuntimeConfig variable calles "hostname" and set it on build time, after it you can use is in the store with this.$config.hostname

Comment: Possible related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278687/showing-the-hostname-in-a-vue-js-template