# "Undefined array key" when cookies are read in php script

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

My html code:

```
<form id="details" action="database_registration.php" class="form">

    Full name: <strong name="name_1">ABC</strong><br><br>
    ID No:<strong name="org_number_1">1</strong><br><br>
    Mobile No:<strong name="ph_number_1">1234567890</strong><br><br>
    
    E-mail: <strong name="email_1">abc@def.com</strong><br><br>
    ID Card: <img src="preview.jpg" alt="preview" name="image" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><br><br>

    <button id="go" onclick="submit()" type="button" value="submit">go</button>
    
</form>
```

My javascript:

```
function submit(){

    var nme=document.getElementsByName("name_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var id=document.getElementsByName("org_number_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var phone=document.getElementsByName("ph_number_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var email=document.getElementsByName("email_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var img=document.getElementsByName("image")[0].src;
 
    document.cookie="name =" + nme;
    document.cookie="ID No =" + id;
    document.cookie="Mobile No =" + phone;
    document.cookie="Email =" + email;
    document.cookie="Image =" + img;
}
```

My php code:

```
<?php
var_dump($_COOKIE['name']);
var_dump($_COOKIE['ID No']);
var_dump($_COOKIE['Mobile No']);
var_dump($_COOKIE['Email']);
var_dump($_COOKIE['Image']);
?>
```

I keep getting the error:

> Undefined array key

for each of the `$_COOKIE` values. Why? I have searched for this error on the internet, and in most cases, it happens mostly because of the fault of the programmer in giving incorrect names. But in my case, all the `keys` are correct. Please help me in fixing this error.

**EDIT:** Taking @Not A Bot's suggestion, I've modified my javascript by using the `fetch()` api:

```
document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', submit);
function submit(){

    var nme=document.getElementsByName("name_1")[0].value;
    var id=document.getElementsByName("org_number_1")[0].value;
    var phone=document.getElementsByName("ph_number_1")[0].value;
    var email=document.getElementsByName("email_1")[0].value;
    var img=document.getElementsByName("image")[0].value;

    document.cookie="name =" + nme;
    document.cookie="ID_No =" + id;
    document.cookie="Mobile_No =" + phone;
    document.cookie="Email =" + email;
    document.cookie="Image =" + img;

    const dForm = document.getElementById('details');          
    dForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch("database_registration.php",{
            method: 'post',
            mode: 'cors',
            body: // what should I add here? 
        }).then(function (response){
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (text){
            console.log(text);
        }).catch(function (error){
            console.error(error);
        })
    });
}
```

Can I add the `document.cookie` in the `body` of the `fetch API`?

Comment: Hi, why are you using getElementsByName instead getElementsByClassname?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_COOKIE);` give you?

Comment: It shows `array(0) {}`

Comment: @Noob Browser automatically sends the cookies to the server. You don't need to send it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use setcookie in the PHP action instead of document.cookie (it works, the problem is this javascript must be executed before, so maybe, you could have problems with that).

You can receive your data in your submit action in PHP and use this line to set the cookie:

```
setcookie('name_of_your_cookie', 'value_of_your_cookie', time() + (86400 * 30)); // 86400 = seconds in 1 day
```

I recommend you write the name of your cookies with the snake case naming convention (name_of_your_cookie) and without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Changes in HTML Code:

- Avoid using `onclick()` [onClick in HTML is Bad Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5871830/11926970)
- Instead of using `action` inside **form** you can send data to the server using AJAX. You can use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [AXIOS](https://github.com/axios/axios) or any other. Since your `action` part is executing and not the JavaScript, thus you are not able to set cookies via JavaScript.
- **Button** does not have a `value` attribute. Even does not need the `type` attribute.

```
<form id="details" class="form">
    Full name: <strong name="name_1">ABC</strong><br><br>

    ID No:<strong name="org_number_1">1</strong><br><br>

    Mobile No:<strong name="ph_number_1">1234567890</strong><br><br>

    E-mail: <strong name="email_1">abc@def.com</strong><br><br>

    ID Card: <img src="preview.jpg" alt="preview" name="image" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><br><br>

    <button id="go">go</button>
    
</form>
```

Changes in JavaScript:

- Use [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) instead of `onclick()`
- Cookie's name should not have space in between words. Example `Mobile No` as cookie name should be avoided as it will work in JavaScript but PHP will give you `NULL`. So change `Mobile No`  to `Mobile_No` and so on.

```
document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', submit);
function submit(){
    var nme=document.getElementsByName("name_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var id=document.getElementsByName("org_number_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var phone=document.getElementsByName("ph_number_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var email=document.getElementsByName("email_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var img=document.getElementsByName("image")[0].src;
 
    document.cookie="name =" + nme;
    document.cookie="ID_No =" + id;
    document.cookie="Mobile_No =" + phone;
    document.cookie="Email =" + email;
    document.cookie="Image =" + img;
}
```

Your PHP is fine, still, to make output looks good you can use `<br />` in-between `var_dump`.

```
<?php
   var_dump($_COOKIE['name']);
   echo   "<br />";
   var_dump($_COOKIE['ID No']);
   echo   "<br />";
   var_dump($_COOKIE['Mobile No']);
   echo   "<br />";
   var_dump($_COOKIE['Email']);
   echo   "<br />";
   var_dump($_COOKIE['Image']);
?>
```

Your **PHP output** looks like something like this:

```
string(3) "ABC"
string(1) "1"
string(10) "1234567890"
string(11) "abc@def.com"
string(11) "preview.jpg"
```

---

---

Update With `Fetch API`

HTML Code:

```
<form id="details" method="post" class="form">
    Full name: <input type="text" name="name_1" /><br><br>

    E-mail: <strong name="email_1">abc@def.com</strong><br><br>

    Mobile: <input type="tel" name="ph_number_1" /><br><br>
    
    <button id="go">go</button>

</form>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var name=document.getElementsByName("name_1")[0].value;
    
    var phone=document.getElementsByName("ph_number_1")[0].value;
    
    var email=document.getElementsByName("email_1")[0].innerHTML;
    
    
    document.cookie="Email =" + email;

    fetch('database_registration.php', {
          method : 'post',
          mode:    'cors',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', // sent request
            'Accept':       'application/json' // expected data sent back
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
             full_name: name, 
             mobile: phone
          })
  })
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
     $contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ?  trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';

     if ($contentType === "application/json") {
 
         $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));

         $decoded = json_decode($content, true);

         $fullName = $decoded["full_name"];
         $mobile = $decoded["mobile"];
         $email = $_COOKIE["Email"];

         $responseToUser = array(
            "result" => "success"
         );
         print_r(json_encode($responseToUser));
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can I send the `document.cookie`  with the help of `Fetch` api?

Comment: @Noob You don't need to send any cookies to the server, the browser automatically sends cookies to the server. So by using ``$_COOKIE['cookie_name']`` to can access the cookie value.

Comment: I've edited the question, using the `fetch` api. But the question is, can I add the `document.cookie` into the `body` of `fetch()`?

Comment: @Noob By adding ``document.cookie`` to the body what do you mean by it? You mean to send cookies or to set cookies?

Comment: I mean what should I add in the `body` ?

Comment: @Noob In this current scenario, you don't need to send anything to the server. Fetch will help you when you are dealing with user data to be stored in DB or something of that type. Here is your scenario, you don't need.

Comment: @Noob I will update my answer to solve your query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227375/discussion-between-noob-and-not-a-bot).

Comment: Doesn't work. Now it shows `POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/database_registration.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)` error

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be much simpler - I had the problem as well: You have to set the path in the cookie. If you redirect from page x to y you will not find the cookie set on x unless you have set the path.

**Example:**

`/shopystem/cart` will not work on `/shopsystem/checkout`

`/shopystem/` will work on `/shopsystem/checkout`

`/shopystem/checkout` will work on `/shopystem/checkout`

Refer to this:
[How to extract the hostname portion of a URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/how-to-extract-the-hostname-portion-of-a-url-in-javascript)