# Get base Url , remove manual

Tags: javascript, base-url

HOw do i get this base path?

http://localhost:1313/

my code right now is

```
 var getUrl = window.location;
  var baseUrl = getUrl .protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

which gives me

http://localhost:1313/manual

**i need to remove "manual"**

Comment: Duplicate Question - You can find an answer at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/how-to-extract-the-hostname-portion-of-a-url-in-javascript/17336519#17336519

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
var baseUrl = window.location.origin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
var getUrl = window.location.origin;
```